# Session variable to show a form or not

Tags: php, forms, session-variables

I want to show a form only if the previous form is filled and submitted. So, I created a session variable which is initialized when I submit the first form. Like this :

```
if( $flag)
            {
                $_SESSION['id_essai'] = $id_essai;
                echo $_SESSION['id_essai'];
                insertion_base($index_essai,$id_essai,$nom_local_essai,$nombre_traitements,$essai_ou_suivis,$thematique);
            }
```

I can get this `var` in this file because my echo works and return the value.

After that :

```
if(isset($_SESSION['id_essai']))
{
    echo'

        <div id="tab_traitement" class="excel"></div>

        <form action="#" method="POST">
            <button  type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="submit_button_traitement">Submit</button>
        </form> ';
}else 
    echo'Pour saisir un traitement, vous devez d\'abord faire la saisie d\'un essai';
```

This is my Index.php :

```
<?php session_start();?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<head>
    <title></title> 
</head>

<body>
        <?php include('onglets.php');?>

</body>
```

In the file 'onglets.php' : I've got :

```
<div class="tabs" id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Essai</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Traitement</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">ITK PRO</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-4">ITK </a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-5">Parcelle élémentaire</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-6">Prélèvement</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-7">Analyse</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-8">Mesure plante principale</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-9">Mesure plante CIPAN</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-10">Station Climatique</a></li>
</ul>

    <div id="tabs-1">
        <?php include('essai.php');?>
    </div>

    <div id="tabs-2">
        <?php include('traitement.php');?>
    </div>

    <div id="tabs-3">
        <?php include('itk_pro.php');?>
    </div>

    <div id="tabs-4">
        <?php include('itk.php');?>
    </div>

    <div id="tabs-5">
        <?php include('pe.php');?>
    </div>

    <div id="tabs-6">
        <?php include('prelevement.php');?>
    </div>

    <div id="tabs-7">
        <?php include('analyse.php');?>
    </div>

    <div id="tabs-8">
        <?php include('mpp.php');?>
    </div>

    <div id="tabs-9">
        <?php include('mpc.php');?>
    </div>

    <div id="tabs-10">
        <?php include('station_climatique.php');?>
    </div>

</div>
<div id="tabid"></div>
```

And I call ajax_insert_essai.php in essai.php. In ajax_insert_essai.php, I initialize $_SESSION['id_essai'].

And I have my `session_start()` at the beginning  without something before so that's not the probem. Please, some help!

How can I do ?

Comment: What does display? else part or what?

Comment: Try to var_dump($_SESSION) and see what's in there

Comment: @SeijiSchoch Yes, there is no value in $_SESSION because I don't find the way to get the value from a file to an other.

Comment: Do you use session_start() on every page?

Comment: @VigneshBala Nothing displays in the file where I want to get the session var, but in the first file I know that $_SESSION['id_essai'] contains my value.

Comment: @SeijiSchoch Yes, that's why I don't understand

Comment: Could you show more of your code? Different pages etc..

Comment: @SeijiSchoch I have only one page but I can update my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you use ajax. Javascript is client side and php is server side.
The page with the form is not recharged, so it isn't processed by the server, so you won't be able to see the session variable unless you refresh the page

Two solutions :

Refresh the page after submitting the first form or use a client-side method, with javascript (better imo)